# SQlite database contains " as part of the word and unable to retrieve it as string

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have database of words which has " in the character.

I use Hotal.ttf fonts as my language doesn't have unicode support(yet).

Word in database is: K"ME@ which looks like this: [image: Oo ji matra]

I am retrieving this from android SQlite database and displaying it in text view.
here is the query code:

```
//Get Meaning
public ArrayList<String> getMeaning(String search) {
    ArrayList<String> meaningList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String searchQuery = "SELECT kMean FROM dictionary WHERE eName LIKE '%" + search + "%' LIMIT 1";

    try {
        Cursor kCursor = this.getDbConnection().rawQuery(searchQuery, null);
        if (kCursor != null) {
            kCursor.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < kCursor.getCount(); i++) {
                String sword = kCursor.getString(kCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("kMean"));
                meaningList.add(sword);
                kCursor.moveToNext();
            }
            kCursor.close();
            return meaningList;
        }
        return meaningList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return meaningList;
}
```

However it is retrieved as this:

[image]

So I think it takes ' instead of " and hence letter [image] is displayed instead of [image]

Help please.

[image]

Comment: you should use a generic type method which replace all specific symbol with allowed symbol in sqlite database and when you are fetching to show in text view revert that symbol with same replaced type symbol

Comment: um.. i have no idea how to do it. can you give me example or something?

Comment: You should post more code.

Comment: @Okas posted the entire code

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code to see what is returned from database?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar In SQLite, *all* Unicode symbols are allowed.

Comment: SQLite does not change the contents of strings, so the problem is either with the data that you're writing, or with the code that displays the string.

Comment: @CL. : I know that In SQLite, all Unicode symbols are allowed, but when he trying to get name with " , it break the query. because in java '' use to pass String, so that's why i have suggest him to replace some symbol with other symbol.

Comment: @CL. I am displaying the results like this TextView.setText(result); does that remove the " from string?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar i cant do that because " is associated in the Hothal.ttf fonts i use and assigned to that key.

Comment: ok. i can understand , but you are applying custom fonts in textview not in a string right? so don't tens i will share some code to do this soon.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar yes by TextView.setTypeface(typeface);

Comment: Are you sure that there is a `"` in the database?

Comment: @CL. wait i'll post screenshot of database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope it will help you something to overcome your problem**

> it will use to encode/decode your string to prevent concatenation
>   breakup

```
private String GenericMethodToCheckString(String name){
        if(name.contains("\"")){
            name= name.replace("\"", "####");
        }
        else if(name.contains("\'")){
            name= name.replace("\'", "##");
        }
        else if(name.contains("##")){
            name= name.replace( "##", "\'");
        }
        else if(name.contains("####")){
            name= name.replace("####", "\"");
        }

        return name;
    }
```

> encode/decode string before store in database

```
    private void InsertInDB(String hotelName){
        hotelName = GenericMethodToCheckString(hotelName);
        // now put your code to insert your hotel name in sqlite db
    }
```

> encode/decode string before search or fetch

```
    //Get Meaning
    public ArrayList<String> getMeaning(String search) {
        search = GenericMethodToCheckString(search);
        ArrayList<String> meaningList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String searchQuery = "SELECT kMean FROM dictionary WHERE eName LIKE '%" + search + "%' LIMIT 1";

        try {
            Cursor kCursor = this.getDbConnection().rawQuery(searchQuery, null);
            if (kCursor != null) {
                kCursor.moveToFirst();
                for (int i = 0; i < kCursor.getCount(); i++) {
                    String sword = kCursor.getString(kCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("kMean"));
                    meaningList.add(sword);
                    kCursor.moveToNext();
                }
                kCursor.close();
                return meaningList;
            }
            return meaningList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return meaningList;
    }
```

> set in `TextView` by this way

```
TextView.setText(GenericMethodToCheckString(meaningList.get(index)));
```

Comment: Solved it, Thank you so much Aniruddh bhai.

Comment: i also need some other help can we chat?

Comment: yeah sure i m free for it

Comment: are you on telegram? i am username @LordSykox

Comment: no i m not using it. my skype id is pariharaniruddh

Comment: i am not there but wait let me sign up...will contact you later thanks a lot again bhai